# Как запрограммировать fixed Joint

Tags: c#, unity3d

подскажите пожалуйста можно ли программно создать fixed joint и так же программно их удалить? Если можно то как?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow.Ru**

создание FixedJoint, [да и любого другого компонента](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.AddComponent.html):

```
FixedJoint joint gameObject.AddComponent<FixedJoint>();
```

указание подсоединенного тела:

```
joint.connectedBody = collision.rigidbody;
```

удаление:

```
Destroy (joint);
```

Comment: а что значит вторая строчка кода не совсем понял

Comment: @danchikon10danchikon10 joint соединяет 2 объекта, я для примера добавил код присвоения тела из описания коллизии

Comment: что такое коллизии

Comment: я просто новичок

Comment: @danchikon10danchikon10 проверка коллизии - это математика, которая возвращает пересеклись(столкнулись) ли объекты https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_detection

Comment: joint.connectedBody это то тело к которому присоединяется joint?правильно я понял?

Comment: @danchikon10danchikon10 да, второе тело, которое вы присоединяете к gameObject этим joint